# Can I ask for recent research papers?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I am a novice student in a field of theoretical CS.

Is it allowed to ask for recent research papers from reputed journals to study?

Answer (score 3):

In principle, questions about what's going on in a small subfield fit into the [reference-request](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag and can be on-topic. ([More](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/what-is-the-reference-request-tag) about this tag.)

A couple of potential pitfalls are:

- Is it something it would make sense to ask your doctoral adviser instead? I think we do want to encourage students to communicate well with their advisers.
- Is the area narrow enough? For instance,

> What's new important work in complexity theory

might be considered [primarily opinion-based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199773/a-question-being-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based), but

> Are there any recent papers (last five years) on 1-counter automata

is more fact-based. In that case, however, there's the question

- Is your question easily answerable using a Google search?

So to summarize, a good question of this kind should be fact-based, answerable, but not easily answerable by a Google search or by your doctoral adviser.